# Android: custom adapter for handling more than one ArayStringLists

Tags: android, arraylist, listadapter

I have a Row layout, with two textViews, lets say textViewX and textViewY. 
I know how to populate one textView with one arrayList using the Adapter.

How do I make a custom Adapter to handle two Array String Lists to populate a row_layout containing two textViews ?

I tried doing this :

```
            // Getting the Text view from the ROW_Layout for Year and adding the text from array string lists 
            TextView yearTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextYear);
            try {
                yearTextView.setText((CharSequence) yearStringList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            yearTextView.setTextColor(0xff444444);  // Setting Dark Grey color to text

            // Getting the Text view from the ROW_Layout for Country and adding the text from array string lists
            TextView countryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCountry);
            try {
                countryTextView.setText((CharSequence) countryStringList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The application crashes, and I checked the logs, and there is a "FATAL ERROR" pointing towards this:

```
yearTextView.setText((CharSequence) yearStringList);
```

Comment: i suggest you to use a model class with getters and setters

Comment: Sorry I am quiet new to Java, and did not managed to understand your explanation.

Comment: first check my post. second what part are you finding difficult to understand.

Comment: i am sure it will work if you do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Model Class

```
class Model
{
String value1;
String value2
public void setValue1(String value1)
{
this.value1=value1;
}
public void setValue2(String value2)
{
this.value2=value2;
}
public String getValue1()
{
return this.value1;
}
public String getValue2()
{
return this.value2;
}
}
```

Now in Activity

```
 ArrayList<Model> aa = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

Now populate the list say using for loop. Below is just an example. Just make sure you populate the list.

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
 Model model = new Model();
 model.setValue1("value1");
 model.setValue2("value2");
 aa.add(model);
 }
```

Pass list `aa` to CustomAdapter and use it there

In getView

```
 Model mo = (Model) aa.get(position);
 tv1.setText(mo.getValue1());
 tv2.setText(mo.getValue2());
```

Comment: If I have two model classes can I use them both in the same adapter?

Comment: you can wrap those two models class with another one. and use that

Comment: im asking this because I have 2 model class(that have a primary key in one and its foriegn key in the other so a join) but I do not know how to do that in one adapter

Comment: @PeterHaddad you should post a new question with relevant details. Someone will answer your question.

Comment: yes i know but I dont want to get downvoted alot, so I will figure it out on my own I guess. Thank you for answering though!

Comment: @PeterHaddad If the question adds value to the site, i don't think you will get downvotes