# Extending ArrayAdapter<String> with two or more List<String>

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a class that extends `ArrayAdapter` (in Android). Originally it was extended by one `List<String>` and it worked fine, but once I added another `List<String>` to the arguments, the `super(`) method started giving out an error: The constructor `ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, int, List<String>, List<String>)` is undefined.

```
public class LocationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final List<String> values;
private final List<String> ids;
private final Context context;
private ListItemListener listener = null;

public LocationListAdapter(Context c, 
        int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> v, List<String> i) {
    super(c, R.layout.location_item, v, i);
    context = c;
    values = v;
    ids = i;
    }
}
```

Is there usually anything wrong with extending ArrayAdapter like that? Thank you!

Comment: is the size of the arraylists the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same size.

Comment: then use `super(c, R.layout.location_item, v);`

Comment: You mean I can specify v to be an object that contains both lists?

Comment: nope pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825768/android-custom-adapter-for-handling-more-than-one-araystringlists/20825922#20825922. if you could post how you populate your 2 lists i can post a more complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create new Object with this strings and specific this list new Object like this:

```
public class TwoString {

private String value;
private String id;

    public TwoString( String id, String value ) {
         this.value = value;
         this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and set them to Adapter

```
public class LocationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TwoString> {

   private final List<TwoString> values;
   private final Context context;
   private ListItemListener listener = null;

public LocationListAdapter( Context c, 
    int textViewResourceId,
    List<TwoString> v) {

    super(c, R.layout.location_item, v );
    context = c;
    values = v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Look at the public constructors. This `ArrayAdapter(Context, int, List, List)` does not match one's in the doc.

`ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
Constructor`

takes context, resource and list as param

Use

```
 super(c, R.layout.location_item, v);
```

You could also consider using a Model class with getters and setters and have a arraylist of model class object.

Edit:

```
class Environment
{
String value1;
String value2
    public Environment(String s1,String s2)
    {
        this.value1 =s1;
        this.value2 =s2;  
    }  
}
```

Now

```
  ArrayList<Environment> e = new   ArrayList<Environment>();
```

To add

```
 e.add(new Environment("s1","s2");
```

Model class with getter and setter. No big diff you have get and set methods that's all

```
class Environment
{
String value1;
String value2
public void setValue1(String value1)
{
this.value1=value1;
}
public void setValue2(String value2)
{
this.value2=value2;
}
public String getValue1()
{
return this.value1;
}
public String getValue2()
{
return this.value2;
}
}
```

Now

```
  ArrayList<Environment> e = new   ArrayList<Environment>();
```

To add

```
 Environment en = new Environment();
 en.setvalue1("s1");
 en.setValue2("s2"); 
 e.add(en);
```

Now pass this list `e` to the constructor of adapter class.

Comment: Yup I see, thank you. Is there any other way to carry the information of two lists in that object I'm creating?

Comment: @AlexKayal yes use a model class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825768/android-custom-adapter-for-handling-more-than-one-araystringlists/20825922#20825922

Comment: @AlexKayal in model class you can have more getters and setters instead of 2 arraylists and have `ArrayList<Model> aa = new ArrayList<Model>()` populate the list with model objects and pass the same to adapter class and use it there

Comment: Thank you. In the project I'm working on (well, I'm extending the code), I have a class called Environment that contains the info in both v and i. It should work if I pass v as List<Environment> I believe.

Comment: @AlexKayal exactly Environment class will have getter and setters. No need for 2 lists.

Comment: Just noticed that our own Environment class was does not have a getter that returns a List. I will implement a simple TwoString class as suggested below to solve it more simplistically.

Comment: @AlexKayal getter and setter is also simple. there is no constructor of TwoString class that take args.

Comment: @AlexKayal pls check the edit. there is no big difference in what i suggested. Its just get and set methods which makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 2 lists as a parameter to array adapter he knows to work only with one array.
Whats the purpose of the second one?